# Line chart for Android with adapter

Tags: android, charts, adapter

I need a line chart that will use adapter like in ListView.

All charts what I saw require array of points as input data. But I have database that contains a lot of points. For drawing this data I should convert selected cursor to an array. It's not suits me. Because in one moment of time on the screen can be displayed scanty part of data. Other points should be displayed only when I do scroll.

Pictures for understanding.

This is what I want:

[image: This is what I want]

What hapened when I scroll:[image: What hapened when I scroll]

New points should be created only when it's needed.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i don't know whether this solution meet your requirement,But you can try [HoloGraphLibrary](https://bitbucket.org/danielnadeau/holographlibrary/wiki/Home)

Which contain all types of graph including line graph

[image]

Wish it will help you,Thank you

Comment: In HoloGraph Library used Line object. Line contains ArrayList that contains Poinst. This is the problem what I described. What I should do if my chart contains 10000 points?